# SQLAlchemy Many-To-Many: AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'is_clause_element'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to build a many-to-many relationship with a middle table, and I'm getting a strange error in secondary argument

```
project-api-1  |   File "falcon/app.py", line 365, in falcon.app.App.__call__
project-api-1  |   File "/code/src/faro/entrypoints/rest/property/resources.py", line 18, in on_get
project-api-1  |     properties = self.search_use_case.execute(
project-api-1  |   File "/code/src/faro/domain/property/use_cases/search.py", line 26, in execute
project-api-1  |     properties = self.property_provider.search(query.district)
project-api-1  |   File "/code/src/faro/domain/property/data_providers/providers.py", line 13, in search
project-api-1  |     query = self.session.query(PropertyEntity)
project-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2143, in query
project-api-1  |     return self._query_cls(entities, self, **kwargs)
project-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 180, in __init__
project-api-1  |     self._set_entities(entities)
project-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 187, in _set_entities
project-api-1  |     self._raw_columns = [
project-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 188, in <listcomp>
project-api-1  |     coercions.expect(
project-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/coercions.py", line 181, in expect
project-api-1  |     insp._post_inspect
project-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 1180, in __get__
project-api-1  |     obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
project-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 2119, in _post_inspect
project-api-1  |     self._check_configure()
project-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1896, in _check_configure
project-api-1  |     _configure_registries({self.registry}, cascade=True)
project-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 3420, in _configure_registries
project-api-1  |     _do_configure_registries(registries, cascade)
project-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 3459, in _do_configure_registries
project-api-1  |     mapper._post_configure_properties()
project-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1913, in _post_configure_properties
project-api-1  |     prop.init()
project-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/interfaces.py", line 231, in init
project-api-1  |     self.do_init()
project-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 2141, in do_init
project-api-1  |     self._process_dependent_arguments()
project-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 2203, in _process_dependent_arguments
project-api-1  |     if self.secondary is not None and _is_mapped_class(self.secondary):
project-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/base.py", line 359, in _is_mapped_class
project-api-1  |     and not insp.is_clause_element
project-api-1  | AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'is_clause_element'
```

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Text, ForeignKey, Numeric, Table, Boolean, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref

property_extras = Table('property_extras', Base.metadata,
                        Column('property_id', Integer, ForeignKey('property.id')),
                        Column('extra_id', Integer, ForeignKey('extras.id'))
                        )

property_images = Table('property_images', Base.metadata,
                        Column('property_id', Integer, ForeignKey('property.id')),
                        Column('image_id', Integer, ForeignKey('images.id')),
                        )

class ExtraEntity(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'extras'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = Column(Text)
    used = Column(Numeric)


class ImageEntity(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'images'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    url = Column(Text)
    public_id = Column(Text)
    
class PropertyEntity(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'property'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    # ...rest of fields
    
    extras = relationship('ExtraEntity',
                               secondary=property_extras,
                               primaryjoin=(property_extras.c.property_id == id),
                               backref=backref('properties', lazy='dynamic'),
                               lazy='dynamic')
    imagesx = relationship('ImageEntity',
                               secondary=property_images,
                               primaryjoin=(property_images.c.property_id == id),
                               backref=backref('property', lazy='dynamic'),
                               lazy='dynamic')
```

**Update:**
Added the calling query:

```
query = self.session.query(PropertyEntity)
result = query.all()
```

**Update 2:**

Initialization code:

```py
        engine = create_engine(container.get(Props.SQL_URI))
        
        from api.data_providers.database.orm.entities import property_images, property_extras, PropertyEntity, PropertyPricingEntity, \
            PropertyUserLikesEntity
        
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        session = Session()
```

```py
# base.py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
```

Comment: I tried to get the error mentioned. But I couldn't reproduce it. Can you add a [Minimal., Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which gives the error

Comment: @rfkortekaas can you try now, I added the missing key

Comment: added the query as well that is the cause of the error

Comment: Which version of SQLAlchemy are you using and which database system? I cannot reproduce this with either SQLite or Postgresql.

Comment: sqlalchemy==1.4.36, 
psycopg2==2.9.3

Comment: @OmarAziz I think your code is doing more stuff than this simple query, I see `self.search_use_case.execute(` and `self.property_provider.search(query.district)` on your traceback, I would check this as well